# Using Moshi in Kotlin (Android), Moshi.adapter() signatures seem to differ from the docs

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, moshi

My build.gradle dependencies (for a non-main Android Studio module):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0'
    ksp 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.14.0'

    // (...)
}
```

This code doesn't work despite seeming to be functionally identical to the examples in the docs:

```
class Blob (val string: String);

internal object JsonMan {
    @NonNull
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                     .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                     .build();

    val mapAdapter = moshi.adapter<Blob>();
                   //      ^^^^^^^ No matching overload found.
}
```

The specific Android Studio error message on hover is:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

*(removed some details for brevity)*

- adapter(Class<TypeVariable(T)!>!)
- adapter(Type!)
- adapter(Type!, (MutableSet<out Annotation!>..Set<Annotation!>?))
- adapter(Type!, (MutableSet<out Annotation!>..Set<Annotation!>?), String?)
- adapter(Type!, Class<out Annotation!>!)
- adapter(type: Type!, annotationType: Class<out Annotation!>!)
- adapter(Type!, vararg Class<out Annotation!>!)
- adapter(type: Type!, vararg annotationTypes: Class<out Annotation!>!)

— basically, **no matching overload found**.

Things I've already tried:

- passing `kotlin.reflect.typeOf<Blob>().javaClass`
- a bunch of nutty rearrangings of the syntax

I was really hoping that simply following the docs would Just Work ™ – I suppose that one's on me.

I'm brand new to Kotlin, so I think I'm probably just ignorant of something that would be obvious to most Moshi-Kotlin users... Any help would be appreciated :)

#### Edit:

The comment by @BeNYaMiN did the trick.

I am a bit salty though that the Kotlin syntax used throughout Moshi's docs aren't an actual signature you can use out of the box... I am still suspicious that there has to be *some* way to get the "official" syntax to compile.  Or is it all because this is Android Kotlin?  If anyone knows, I would still appreciate your knowledge!

Comment: Use it like this: `val mapAdapter = moshi.adapter(Blob::class.java)`.

Comment: Moshi does have some reified Kotlin extension methods. You might have to paste the import statement manually? `import com.squareup.moshi.adapter`

Comment: @Eric Cochran  - That does work too, _IFF_ I also decorate the scope with `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)`...  I only have a cursory understanding of Kotlin reification, so in this instance I think I'll leave the "experimental" APIs to the folks who are more familiar with this lang + env.

Answer (score 2):

Wow... thank you @BeNYaMiN!

```
val mapAdapter = moshi.adapter(Blob::class.java)
```

Finally works